# Angular nested state has to use $scope.parent from same controller, why?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a table, which loops over a scope called $scope.sites.

I'm submitting a form which saves a new site to a DB, and then adds to the site scope.

However, when I update $scope.sites, it doesn't update the table. The table is under the same SiteCtrl controller.

The scope is definitely being appended to, as if I output {{ sites.length }} after the form has posted, its value increases (and the data appears in the DB).

If I add

```
{{ sites.length }}
```

to the same part that the form is included (in the ui-view) it updates, outside of that and it doesn't.

Here's some of the code:

### The Javascript

Note, I'm using ui-router for nested states.

```
myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

// The default route
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

$stateProvider

    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'app/partials/welcome.html',
        controller: 'WelcomeCtrl'
    })
    .state('entity', {
        url: '/entity/:id',
        params: { id: "" },
        templateUrl: 'app/partials/entity/index.html',
        controller: 'EntityCtrl'
    })
    .state('entity.site', {
        url: '/site',
        templateUrl: 'app/partials/site/index.html',
        controller: 'SiteCtrl'
    })
    .state('entity.site.create', {
        url: '/create',
        templateUrl: 'app/partials/site/create.html',
        controller: 'SiteCtrl'
    })
```

....

```
myApp.controller('SiteCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$stateParams', function($scope, $http, $stateParams) {

$scope.entity_id = $stateParams.id;
$scope.site_uuid = $stateParams.siteuuid;

$scope.sites = {};
$scope.site = {};
$scope.errors = {};
$scope.result = {};
$scope.formData = {};

$http({ method: 'GET', url: 'siteurl' }).
    success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.sites= data.data;
    }).
    error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(data.result);
        console.log(data.code);
    });


$scope.submitForm = function() {


    $http.post('submiturl', $scope.formData).success(function(data) {

        //Clear the form
        $scope.formData = {};

        $scope.site = data.data;
        $scope.sites.push($scope.site);


    }).error(function(data){
        $scope.errors = data;
    });
}



}]);
```

### The HTML

```
<div ng-controller="SiteCtrl">

<h1>Sites <a ui-sref="entity.site.create" class="btn"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add New Site</a></h1>

<ui-view></ui-view> <!---- The form is included here by a ui-router state --->


<pre>{{ sites.length }}</pre> <!-- this doesnt update, nor does the table --->

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="filter">Filter</label>
    <input ng-model="filter" class="form-control">
</div>

<table class="striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="site in sites | filter:filter">
        <td><a ui-sref="entity.site.show({siteuuid:site.uuid})" ui-sref-active="child-active">{{ site.name }}</a></td>

    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

### The Form

```
<h1>Create a New Site at {{ entity.name }} <a ui-sref="entity.site" class="btn">Close</a></h1></h1>

<pre>{{ result }}</pre>
<pre>{{ errors }}</pre>
<pre>{{ site }}</pre>
<pre>{{ sites.length }}</pre> <!---- This updates --->

<form name="createNewSiteForm" method="post" ng-submit="submitForm()">

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Site Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="formData.name" autocomplete="off" required />
    {{ errors.name }}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" name="create" value="Save {{ formData.name }}" />
</div>

</form>
```

The form is included as a nested view in the

If there's anything else you'd like to see let me know and I can post it up.

## Update

So the solution was to use:

```
$scope.parent.sites.push($scope.site);
```

My question is, do I have to use the parent, when the scope should be inherited due to being in the same Controller?

I'm new to Angular shedding some light on this would be very useful for my learning.

Comment: Your fiddle does nothing (besides displaying the code..)

Comment: I've removed the fiddle as it wasn't possible to get it encapsulated and working due to there being so much code. The relevant subset is above.